# I am trying to generate documentation from library jazzy,but i am getting following error

Tags: ios, xcode, jazzy

The Project is basically made in objective-c language.

[Jazzy Github Library](https://github.com/realm/jazzy)

Running xcodebuild
Could not parse compiler arguments from `xcodebuild` output.
Please confirm that `xcodebuild` is building a Swift module.
Saved `xcodebuild` log file: /var/folders/n1/3bl62xcd1_g3f22vy5w_rmhc0000gn/T/xcodebuild-BB10C494-E3B5-49A1-959E-EEBB136703E6.log
Failed to generate documentation
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/executable.rb:36:in `execute_command': /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/SourceKitten/bin/sourcekitten ["doc", "--"] (RuntimeError)

Running xcodebuild

Could not parse compiler arguments from `xcodebuild` output.

Please confirm that `xcodebuild` is building a Swift module.

Saved `xcodebuild` log file: /var/folders/n1/3bl62xcd1_g3f22vy5w_rmhc0000gn/T/xcodebuild-BB10C494-E3B5-49A1-959E-EEBB136703E6.log

Failed to generate documentation
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/sourcekitten.rb:147:in `run_sourcekitten'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:64:in`block in build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:62:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/lib/jazzy/doc_builder.rb:62:in`build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jazzy-0.7.2/bin/jazzy:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/jazzy:22:in`load'
    from /usr/bin/jazzy:22:in `'

Answer (score 2):

Try running this:

```
jazzy --min-acl internal -x -workspace,WORKSPACE.xcworkspace,-scheme,SCHEMA
```

Replace WORKSPACE and SCHEMA with your values.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not running jazzy from the correct directory.

Try running `xcodebuild` in the same folder, as you were using for running jazzy when receiving the error.